# Highchart not load JSON data

Tags: php, json, highcharts

I have a page that uses highcharts pie chart with JSON data in it, My chart is not showing in browser but json data is showing like this :

```
[{"type":"pie","name":"Progress Fisik","data":[["rencana",89.4554],["realisasi",82.1436]]}]
```

Here my chart.js:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
        var options = {
            chart: {
                renderTo: 'donut_chart',
                plotBackgroundColor: null,
                plotBorderWidth: null,
                plotShadow: false
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
                },
                 exporting: {
                    enabled: false
                },
            title: {
                text: 'Progres Fisik',
                align: 'center',
                verticalAlign: 'middle'
            },
             
            plotOptions: {
                 pie: {
                    allowPointSelect: false,
                    startAngle: 180,
                    innerSize: '70%',
                    cursor: 'pointer',
                        dataLabels: {
                        enabled: true,
                        color: '#000000',
                        connectorColor: '#000000',
                        formatter: function() {
                            return '<b>' + this.point.name+ '</b> : '+ this.point.y;
                        }
                    }
                }
            },
            series: [{
                    type: 'pie',
                    innerSize: '50%',
                    colorByPoint: true,
                    data: []
            }]
        }
        $.getJSON("data.php", function(json) {
            options.series = json;
            chart = new Highcharts.Chart(options);
        });
    });
```

And Here data.php :

```
include 'db-config.php';
$balai = mysqli_real_escape_string($config, $_GET['balai']);
$query = mysqli_query($config, "SELECT* FROM data_balai WHERE kode_balai='$balai'");
$rows['type'] = 'pie';
$rows['name'] = 'Progress Fisik';
while ($r = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $rows['data'][0] = array('rencana', $r['ren_fisik']);
    $rows['data'][1] = array('realisasi', $r['real_fisik']);
}
$rslt = array();
array_push($rslt, $rows);
print json_encode($rslt, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK);
mysqli_close($config);
```

What do i need to do to fix my code above?

Comment: Hi @Andri, Your code seems to work fine. Are you sure that it is correctly fired? Live example with your code: http://jsfiddle.net/BlackLabel/xzpck695/

Comment: Thanks @ppotaczek, but it seems the code above has a problem with my "get method", from the "get method" the json still runs fine, but the chart doesn't display the data. maybe there is something i need to add to my chart code ?

Comment: Yes, you are right. I would suggest to use `fail` property or close `$.getJSON` in try/catch and check what is the error. API: https://api.jquery.com/jquery.getjson/